# Most appropriate phrasing of a sentence containing an exception

Tags: word-choice, sentence, syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage

Consider the following two paragraphs:

**The data was compelling. It appears that all of the companies abandoned that manufacturing method - with one exception - when it was determined to be less efficient.**

**The data was compelling. With one exception, it appears that all of the companies abandoned that manufacturing method when it was determined to be less efficient.**

The idea being conveyed is that one company did not abandon a manufacturing method upon studying data. Both paragraphs convey this information, but in two different ways. I am curious as to which one is more correct if the criteria is proper English.

Comment: There is no basic difference between using a single comma or paired em dashes in order to introduce nonessential information. It's purely a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1):

How about "all but one of the companies" etc.

I would drop the "it appears" because it seems like a needless hedge. Also, I would either drop the "when it was determined" part, or put it as a separate sentence. Also I would drop the "determined to be." It could indicate that the method has determination and chose to be less efficient.

**The data was compelling. The manufacturing method was less efficient. All but one of the companies abandoned the method.**

Presumably somewhere nearby you have established that there are several companies.

Comment: Great advice. The new sentence I'm going with is not exactly as your answer puppetsock, but I've borrowed your much better phrasing "all but one of the companies... ". Thanks. I tried to upvote but I don't have enough points yet. Will attempt to again later.

Comment: Despite the positive reaction to this answer, it doesn't actually answer the question. Instead, it provides proofreading advice which is off topic here. The *actual* question is if there is a difference between using a single comma and a pair of em dashes when providing nonessential information. (The answer to which is, no. It's purely stylistic and a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: It isn't necessarily helpful to provide answers in a "letter of the law" kind of manner. The poster was clearly asking how to present the idea, not *only* which of the two presented alternatives was correct.